# Accidentally Disassemble AppleRAID RAID0

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I accidentally disassembled a RAID1 via Disk Utility. The two disks were originally formatted to APFS. The Apple official website claimed the data recorded on the disks is not deleted. However, after being deleted both disks cannot be mounted.

I then run the following commands:

```
gpt show /dev/disk4
        start         size  index  contents
            0            1         PMBR
            1            1         Pri GPT header
            2           32         Pri GPT table
           34            6         
           40       409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
       409640  15627381344      2  GPT part - 52414944-5F4F-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  15627790984       262144      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  15628053128            7         
  15628053135           32         Sec GPT table
  15628053167            1         Sec GPT header
```

I searched the `GUID 52414944-5F4F-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`. This returned a type called `Apple_RAID_Offline`. I also found this paragraph:

- https://chrislloyd.co/repairing-appleraid/

This solution looks promising. However, the disks in this paragraph were formatted as HFS+. I tried to replace HFS+ with APFS GUID, however, I had no luck mounting them and I think maybe APFS partition table is more complex and is out of my knowledge.

Could anyone have similar situations before share? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: You aren't trying to mount them individually, are you?  Rather than attempting to reconstitute the RAID0?  The article you link describes a procedure to gain access to one disk of a mirror set, ie RAID1.

Comment: Hi Marc, sorry, I made a typo. It is a RAID1, mirror set, so data exists identically on both disks.

Comment: In the first paragraph, you said “after being deleted, both disks….”  What did you delete, the array itself  or the data on the disk(s)?  Next, you said that they were originally HFS+ but you tried to “replace with with APFS.”  Did you do this to both disks or just one?  How did you do this?  Please note that HFS+ and APFS are very different animals and you can’t just “toggle” between the two.  One last question…you did back up your data before doing this?

Comment: @moon_crawler OK, how did you disassemble the RAID?  Removing a member should not have destroyed the array.  Removing the**array** would have deleted the data necessitating a restoral from backup.